# bash call script with variable

Tags: bash, shell

What I want to achieve is the following :
I want the subtitles for my TV Show downloaded automatically.
The script "getSubtitle.sh" is ran as soon as the show is downloaded, but it can happen that no subtitle are released yet.

So what I am doing to counter this :
Creating a file each time "getSubtitle.sh" is ran. It contain the location of the script with its arguments, for example :

```
/Users/theo/logSubtitle/getSubtitle.sh "The Walking Dead - 5x10 - Them.mp4" "The.Walking.Dead.S05E10.480p.HDTV.H264.mp4" "/Volumes/Window HD/Série/The Walking Dead"
```

If a subtitle has been found, this file will contain only this line, if no subtitle has been found, this file will have 2 lines (the first one being "no subtitle downloaded", and the second one being the path to the script as explained above)

Now, once I get this, I'm planning to run a cron everyday that will do the following :

Remove all file that have only 1 line (Subtitle found), and execute the script again for the remaining file. Here is the full script :

```
cd ~/logSubtitle/waiting/
for f in *
do nbligne=$(wc -l $f | cut -c 8)
if [ "$nbligne" = "1" ]
then
rm $f
else
command=$(sed -n "2 p" $f)
sh $command 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | grep down > $f ; echo $command >> $f
fi
done
```

This is unfortunately not working, I have the feeling that the script is not called.

When I replace $command by the line in the text file, it is working.
I am sure that $command match the line because of the "echo $command >> $f" at the end of my script.

So I really don't get what I am missing here, any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please start from the beginning and explain it from scratch what you want to do. Your code doesn't make much sense. (What is `$f`? Is the code part of `genSubtitle.sh`? ...) When you pass variables to a shell script you can get the number of arguments in `$#` and first argument in `$1`, next in `$2` etc.

Comment: Didn't think it was relevant to explain it all, but I just edited the post. $f is just the name of the file that the script is processing. I don't have any trouble with passing arguments, I have trouble getting my script called with the sed line

Comment: For starters, this `3>&1 1>&2 2>&3`: What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: This is just a way to redirect the stdout of the script. This is not the problem as I am using it in the script that get the subtitle in the first place, and that it is working when I replace "sh $command 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | grep down > $f ; echo $command >> $f" by "sh ~/logSubtitle/getSubtitle.sh "The Walking Dead - 5x10 - Them.mp4" "The.Walking.Dead.S05E10.480p.HDTV.H264.mp4" "/Volumes/Window HD/Série/The Walking Dead" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | grep down > $f ; echo $command >> $f"

Comment: You're switching place of stdout and stderr, makes no sense to me atleast :) Anyway, try using `eval` instead of `sh`, does it make things happier?

Comment: THANKS ! Working fine with eval. Even tho I'm not sure to really see the difference between those 2 (eval execute the script inside this one, when sh start an other script ?)
I am redirecting stderr into stdout because I need to grep the output of the subtitle search. And it seems the script I am using (subliminal) send is output to stderr.
I'm not use to SO, because you answered it in comments, how can I say you solved it ?

Comment: I added an answer that also explains why it works with eval. Btw, if you just want to redirect stderr to stdout, just to `2>&1` and nothing else.

Comment: @Loneept, I'd strongly suggest thinking about what the code you're writing will do when files are maliciously named. For instance, you very much don't want to put the name of a file created with the command  `touch 'Hello $(rm -rf .) world'` inside double quotes and pass that as code to a shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eval` instead of `sh`. The reason it works with `eval` and not `sh` is due to the number of passes to evaluate variables. `sh` will treat the `sed` command as its command to execute while `eval` will evaluate the `sed` command first and then execute the result.

Briefly explained.

Comment: This is true, but it's also a bad way to solve problems in bash in general -- see BashFAQ #48: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048; granted, explicitly calling an external shell with paramaterized values passed as code (without dropping privileges or sandboxing) has the same security problems, but then, encouraging folks to engage in that practice is best avoided also.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I haven't encouraged anything, I'm merely answering his question, or questions, one of them in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the `cut -c 8` part in `wc -l $f | cut -c 8`. `cut -c 8` will select the 8th character of the output of `wc -l`.

A suggestion: to check whether your file contains 1 or two lines (and since you'll need the content of the second line, if any, anyway), use `mapfile`. This will slurp the file in an array, one line per field. You can use the option `-n 2` to read at most 2 lines. This will be much more efficient, safe and nice than your solution:

```
mapfile -t -n 2 ary < file
```

Then:

```
if ((${#ary[@]}==1)); then
    printf 'File contains one line only: %s\n' "${ary[0]}"
elif ((${#ary[@]==2)); then
    printf 'File contains (at least) two lines:\n'
    printf '   %s\n' "${ary[@]}"
else
    printf >&2 'Error, no lines found in file\n'
fi
```

Another suggestion: ***use more quotes!***

With this, a better way to write your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$HOME/logSubtitle/waiting/

shopt -s nullglob

for f in "$dir"/*; do
    mapfile -t -n 2 ary < "$f"
    if ((${#ary[@]}==1)); then
        rm -- "$f" || printf >&2 "Error, can't remove file %s\n" "$f"
    elif ((${#ary[@]}==2)); then
        { sh -c "${ary[1]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | grep down; echo "${ary[1]}"; } > "$f"
    else
        printf >&2 'Error, file %s contains no lines\n' "$f"
    fi
done
```

After the `done` keyword you can even add the redirection `2>> logfile` to a log file if you wish. Make sure the cron job is run with your user: check `crontab -l` and, if needed, edit it with `crontab -e`.

Comment: A much easier fix is `wc -l<"$f"`. I'm guessing the `cut` is to get rid of the filename, but it will obviously produce false positives for other numbers whose last digit is 1.

Comment: @tripleee: Sure it's an easier fix. Yet, it's useless (in this case) to call an external program to count the number of lines as, anyway, we'll need the content of the second line later (see OP's `sed -n '2 p' "$f"` command). We might as well slurp all that in an array (and in pure Bash) and we'll have all the information needed once for all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try to improve my script with theses advice :)